What is the name of this combinatorial identity?
In the course of my physics research, I appear to have stumbled onto the following combinatorial identity:
$${dn\choose m}=\sum_{\vec k} {n \choose \vec k}\,\prod_{j=0}^d {d \choose j}^{k_j},$$
where $\vec k$ is a vector
$$\vec k=(k_0,k_1,\ldots,k_d)$$
of non-negative integers. In the identity, we sum over all $\vec k$ that are solutions of the Diophantine equations
$$\sum_{j=0}^d k_j=n$$
$$\sum_{j=0}^d j\,k_j=m$$
and we let ${n \choose \vec k}$ denote the multinomial. Note that these conditions require $0\leq m\leq dn$.
Does anyone know the name for this identity, and/or have a reference to it?

I don't know if that one specifically is known by some name, but it is particular case/consequence of Faa di Bruno's formula

These quantities seem related to Bell polynomials; maybe that's helpful....

Not sure this has a name. The identity can be obtained by expanding  both sides of $$(1+x)^{dn}=((1+x)^d)^n=\left(\sum_{j=0}^{d}\binom{d}{j}x^j\right)^n,$$ and the identity can be also expressed using Bell polynomials: $$\binom{nd}{m}=\frac{n!}{m!}\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{1}{k!} B_{m,n-k}((d)_1, (d)_2, \ldots, (d)_d), $$ where $d_j=\frac{d!}{(d-j)!}$ is the falling factorial.

@SangchulLee "expanding" compositions, in particular that one, is what Faa di Bruno's formula does.

Thank you! Could you all make these answers so I can accept one of them?

@ameg, That's a nice observation! I was thinking of manually expanding the right-hand side but your idea certainly provides a systematical way. I guess you can expand your argument and write up an answer, so OP can accept it!

This is also a restatement of Theorem 2 part II in Qimh Richey Xantcha, Binomial Rings: Axiomatisation, Transfer and Classification, arXiv:1104.1931v4, which is saying that
\begin{align*}
\dbinom{ab}{n} = \sum_{m=0}^n \dbinom{a}{m} \sum_{\substack{q_1 + q_2 + \cdots + q_m = n\\ \text{with all } q_i \geq 1}} \dbinom{b}{q_1} \dbinom{b}{q_2} \cdots \dbinom{b}{q_m}
\end{align*}
for all nonnegative integers $n$ and all numbers (e.g., integers, but could just as well be complex numbers or elements of any commutative $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra) $a$ and $b$.
Your reformulation is obtained by replacing the $m$-tuple $\left(q_1, q_2, \ldots, q_m\right)$ by its multiplicity sequence $\overline{k}$. The details are rather annoying to explain and get right (in particular, there is a disagreement about whether $q_i = 0$ is allowed and whether $m\leq n$ or $m=n$, but this boils down to the same result upon simple combinatorial transformations). You might have an easier life proving your formula on your own: Combinatorially, both formulas (in the case when $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative integers) come from double-counting the $n$-element subsets of the discrete $a\times b$-rectangle $\left\{1,2,\ldots,a\right\} \times \left\{1,2,\ldots,b\right\}$. (To get Xantcha's right hand side, you drop the empty rows and split the sum according to how many points are included on each nonempty row. To get your right hand side, you split the sum according to how many rows have $0$ selected points, how many have $1$ selected point, and so on.) But the above reference might be useful as it discusses several similar formulas and situates them in their "proper" conceptual place.
